# Can a Service Write to Registry [HKLM]

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-vista, windows-services, uac

I am writing a service for Windows Vista/7 which needs read/write/delete access to the registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons

Are there any special considerations I must make just in case the target system has UAC enabled and the service must always run with administrator privileges?

The service is being written in VB.NET but C# code is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) (UAC) only applies to users who are logged on interactively. A windows service will have the full security token (as opposed to the restricted one UAC generates for non-standard account users) available to it.

If your service is running as either `Administrator`, a member of the `Administrators` group or `LOCALSYSTEM`, it should have unrestricted access to HKLM. The only thing you may need to be aware of is [registry redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28VS.85%29.aspx) for 32bit processes running on 64bit Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The only issue to consider is that the service must run under an account that has Registry read/write/delete access to the specified key.